# Add image in pdf using jspdf

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, jspdf

I am using jspdf to convert an image into a PDF.

I have converted the image into a URI using base64encode. But the problem is that there are no errors or warnings shown in the console.

A PDF is generated with the text Hello World on it but no image is added in it.

Here is my code.

```
function convert(){
        var doc = new jsPDF();
        var imgData = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+ Base64.encode('Koala.jpeg');
        console.log(imgData);
        doc.setFontSize(40);
        doc.text(30, 20, 'Hello world!');
        doc.output('datauri');
        doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 15, 40, 180, 160);

    }
```

Comment: What is the question here ?

Comment: A wild guess would be that he or she wishes for the img to show on the pdf

Comment: @Brainmaniac A wild guess /:) I think the question was before an edit or something like that

Answer (score 47):

This worked for me in Angular 2:

```
var img = new Image()
img.src = 'assets/sample.png'
pdf.addImage(img, 'png', 10, 78, 12, 15)
```

jsPDF version 1.5.3

**assets** directory is in **src** directory of the Angular project root

Comment: This worked for me. Until I add 'png' to addImage, it didn' work.

Comment: Didn't work for me either whilst specifying the extension. 

  handler: "Error: Incomplete or corrupt PNG file"

Comment: This worked for me when setting the src to a base64 encoded image.

Answer (score 24):

Though I'm not sure, the image might not be added because you create the output before you add it. Try:

```
function convert(){
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    var imgData = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+ Base64.encode('Koala.jpeg');
    console.log(imgData);
    doc.setFontSize(40);
    doc.text(30, 20, 'Hello world!');
    doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 15, 40, 180, 160);
    doc.output('datauri');
}
```

Comment: What are all the parameters for the addImage function?

Comment: @Grez.Kev It has been a while ago, but if I remember correctly it is: addImage(image, format, xPosition, yPosition, width, height). I hope this helps!

Comment: It is `addImage(imageData, format, x, y, width, height, alias, compression, rotation)`. Read https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-addImage.html

Comment: `Base64.encode('filename.jpeg')` no encode the image, this way will only do for the file name?!

Comment: can we make height and width 100%, I mean can we make an image fit according to available space in pdf

Answer (score 16):

maybe a little bit late, but I come to this situation recently and found a simple solution, 2 functions are needed.

1. load the image.

   ```
   function getImgFromUrl(logo_url, callback) {
       var img = new Image();
       img.src = logo_url;
       img.onload = function () {
           callback(img);
       };
   }
   ```
2. in onload event on first step, make a callback to use the jspdf doc.

   ```
   function generatePDF(img){
       var options = {orientation: 'p', unit: 'mm', format: custom};
       var doc = new jsPDF(options);
       doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 0, 0, 100, 50);}
   ```
3. use the above functions.

   ```
   var logo_url = "/images/logo.jpg";
   getImgFromUrl(logo_url, function (img) {
       generatePDF(img);
   });
   ```

Comment: what is the custom format: custom? I am getting error Uncaught ReferenceError: custom is not defined

Answer (score 16):

No need to add any extra base64 library. **Simple 5 line solution -**

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = path.resolve('sample.jpg');

var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a3');  // optional parameters
doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 1, 2);
doc.save("new.pdf");
```

Comment: path.resolve is Node JS stuff. It basically figures out the correct file path relative to your file. If you don't want to use it you can provide file source (/something/something/myfile.jpg) instead of path.resolve()

Comment: You're loading a 'jpg' file, but you're setting it as 'png'  in `doc.addImage`

Comment: @MustkeemK You can go through this link: https://artskydj.github.io/jsPDF/docs/module-addImage.html

Comment: in latter versions, addImage expects 4 arguments.

Comment: instead of doc.save("new.pdf"); can we use doc.open("new.pdf") to open that pdf file in new tab/window. ?

Answer (score 6):

You defined Base64? If you not defined, occurs this error:

> ReferenceError: Base64 is not defined

Comment: You can use an online converter and insert string into your code. https://www.base64-image.de/

Answer (score 4):

I find it useful.

```
var imgData = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,verylongbase64;'

var doc = new jsPDF();

doc.setFontSize(40);
doc.text(35, 25, "Octonyan loves jsPDF");
doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 15, 40, 180, 180);
```

http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/

Answer (score 4):

The above code not worked for me.
I found new solution :

```
 var pdf = new jsPDF();
 var img = new Image;
 img.onload = function() {
     pdf.addImage(this, 10, 10);
     pdf.save("test.pdf");
 };
 img.crossOrigin = "";  
 img.src = "assets/images/logo.png";
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with Base64 not being defined. I went to [an online encoder](https://www.base64-image.de/) and then saved the output into a variable. This probably is not ideal for many images, but for my needs it was sufficient.

```
function makePDF(){
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    var image = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAA..";
    doc.addImage(image, 'JPEG', 15, 40, 180, 160);
    doc.save('title');
}
```

Comment: You have image/png but add as jpg. That does not sound right

Comment: @mplungjan `data:image/png` is just typo error, with `data:image/jpeg` everything is alright

Answer (score 2):

if you have

> ReferenceError: Base64 is not defined

you can upload your file [here](https://dataurl.sveinbjorn.org/#dataurlmaker) you will have something as :

> data:image/jpeg;base64,/veryLongBase64Encode....

on your js do :

```
var imgData = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/veryLongBase64Encode....'
var doc = new jsPDF()

doc.setFontSize(40)
doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 15, 40, 180, 160)
```

Can see example [here](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf/doc/symbols/jspdf.html)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to load the image, convert data, and then pass to jspdf (in typescript):

```
loadImage(imagePath): ng.IPromise<any> {
    var defer = this.q.defer<any>();
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = imagePath;
    img.addEventListener('load',()=>{
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.width = img.width;
            canvas.height = img.height;

            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');

            defer.resolve(dataURL);
    });

    return defer.promise;
}

generatePdf() {
    this.loadImage('img/businessLogo.jpg').then((data) => {
        var pdf = new jsPDF();
        pdf.addImage(data,'JPEG', 15, 40, 180, 160);
        pdf.text(30, 20, 'Hello world!');
        var pdf_container =  angular.element(document.getElementById('pdf_preview'));
        pdf_container.attr('src', pdf.output('datauristring'));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For result in base64, before convert to canvas:

```
var getBase64ImageUrl = function(url, callback, mine) {

                    var img = new Image();

                    url = url.replace("http://","//");

                    img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');

                    img.onload = function () {
                        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                        canvas.width =this.width;
                        canvas.height =this.height;

                        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);

                        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(mine || "image/jpeg");

                        callback(dataURL);
                    };
                    img.src = url;

                    img.onerror = function(){

                        console.log('on error')
                        callback('');

                    }

            }

   getBase64ImageUrl('Koala.jpeg', function(img){
         //img is a base64encode result
         //return img;
          console.log(img);

          var doc = new jsPDF();
              doc.setFontSize(40);
              doc.text(30, 20, 'Hello world!');
              doc.output('datauri');
              doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 15, 40, 180, 160);
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

In TypeScript, you can do:

```
private getImage(imagePath): ng.IPromise<any> {
    var defer = this.q.defer<any>();
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = imagePath;
    img.addEventListener('load',()=>{
       defer.resolve(img);
    });


    return defer.promise;
}
```

Use the above function to getimage object. Then the following to add to pdf file:

```
pdf.addImage(getImage(url), 'png', x, y, imagewidth, imageheight);
```

In plain JavaScript, the function looks like this:

```
function (imagePath) {
        var defer = this.q.defer();
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = imagePath;
        img.addEventListener('load', function () {
            defer.resolve(img);
        });
        return defer.promise;
    };
```