# css - printing exact size

Tags: html, css, printing

I need to print a web page on regular A4 page.

The print result should be exactly 20cm x 20cm (no matter it's position on paper).

I have this html page:

```css
body {
  -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
  height: 20cm;
  width: 20cm;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

img {
  height: 20cm;
  width: 20cm;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 0.9cm;
  position: relative;
  top: 1cm;
  text-align: center;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #ffde00;
}

@media print {
  body {
    height: 20cm;
    width: 20cm;
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="background.png">
<h1>My Example Text</h1>
```

When I am printing this page (on a regular lasterJet A4 printer) I am getting about 18.9cm result on the paper.

How can I make it exactly 20cm ?

Comment: use `@page size` property

Comment: My guess is that the printer driver resizes the body to fit the page. See if you can find a setting like that. And/or, reduce the margins. Also, if the body is 20cm high, can you fit a 20cm img plus a 0.9cm h1 into it?

Comment: @santosh try to use that, still not getting 20cm exact

Comment: @mplungjan what do you mean?

Comment: @mplungjan what do you mean by serve a pdf ?

Comment: `<link rel="alternate" href="print.pdf" hreflang="en" type="application/pdf" media="print">`

Comment: @mplungjan I dont have pdf file, and I dont want to create one (I have many web pages like this one)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065562/add-image-in-pdf-using-jspdf

Comment: It could simply be that the printable area of your printer is less than 20cm wide (which wouldn't be unusual for an A4 printer)

Answer (score 0):

To set the print area you can use @media print
an example:

```
/* style sheet for “letter” printing */
@media print and (width: 1.5in) and (height: 1in) {
@page {
margin: 1in;
}
}
```