# print local image to pdf using jsPDF

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf

I would add an image to a pdf File.

```
const pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'px', 'a4');
const imgData = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + btoa(`assets/img/brand/png/Logos.png`);
console.log(imgData);
pdf.addImage(imgData, 'jpeg', 15, 40, 180, 160);
pdf.save(`ind.pdf`);
```

I get an error

```
 Error: addImage does not support files of type 'UNKNOWN'
```

I think that the error comes from `btoa()` it encode the path string but not the file.

How can I pass to btoa the png image instead of the path string ?

Comment: this question should not be tagged Angular

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add image in pdf using jspdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065562/add-image-in-pdf-using-jspdf)

Comment: @Harry It could be an angular error, I maybe should call the file differently.

Comment: @window.document In my example I add Image before output but does not work

Answer (score 4):

When I was trying to use an image file instead of a Base64 encoded image I had trouble with the version of jsPDF.  After I changed to use the latest version of jsPDF, then this worked.

```js
function fnProcess() {

  var img = new Image();
  var src = "https://www.jeffld.com/img/so/testimage001.png";
  img.src = src;

  console.log("Create jsPDF object");
  var pdf = new jsPDF("p", "pt", "letter");

  console.log("Add Image");
  pdf.addImage(img, "png", 10, 10, 150, 150);

  console.log("Save PDF");
  pdf.save("file.pdf");
  console.log("done");
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest version of jsPDF Version 1.5.3 Built on 2018-12-27T14:11:42.696Z -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf@latest/dist/jspdf.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="fnProcess()">Process</button>

<p>Image to PDF</p>    
<img id="activityLogo" src="https://www.jeffld.com/img/so/testimage001.png" alt="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to print an uploaded image.

````
  let image = new Image();
  let source = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]); //general case
  image.src = source ;

  let pdf = new jsPDF();
  pdf.addImage(image, "jpeg", 10, 20, 300, 300);

  pdf.save("image.pdf");
}```
````